# Analyse sql queries text

Tags: c#, python, sql, t-sql

I faced with problem:

There is a big old database on microsoft sql server (with triggers, functions etc.). I am writing C# app on top of this db. Most of work is a "experiments" like this:

Write a part of functionality and see if it works in old Delphi app (i.e. inserted data in C# loaded correctly in Delphi).

So I need tool, that can determine which fields of each table is used or not (used in my queries). I think to write python script with sql syntax analyser or just using regular expressions.

What solution would you recommend?

Comment: ...if you're writing the queries, what do you need this information for?  If this is for queries other people have written, writing an external script is going to be thwarted pretty fast by dynamic SQL; you'd probably be better off putting a monitor on the DB.  So what is it you're trying to accomplish here?  Why do you think you need a list of columns?

Comment: I need fast easy way to see what part of db is used. So monitor on the DB is my solution. Sorry for unclear question and later reaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run a trace in SQL Profiler to see the queries being executed on the server.